# Transaction waits for committ and otherwise blocks resources

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions

I would like to put a few statements into a transaction block so that, in case of any error the script rolls back. I combine a transaction with a `TRY` block like this (and note that the `INSERT` statement should through a syntax error):

```
begin try
    begin tran
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    CREATE TABLE [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE](
        [Id] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    insert into [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (Id,Name) values ('1','Vampire'),  ('2')
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran
end catch
```

After running this statement, I noticed that I cannot fetch my other tables in Management Studio and that the operation is waiting for me to commit.

How can I alter my transaction-try blocks so that in case of any error, we rollback to where we were before the `begin try` statement?

Comment: `TRY...CATCH` doesn't "catch" Syntax Errors. You need to address those yourself in your code.

Comment: @Larnu You are right. But would it work otherwise, you think?

Comment: If the error was something that `TRY...CATCH` catches, then yes, then above should work. The easy way to tell would be fix the syntax error and test.

Comment: @Larnu True. But how could we know if that unpredictable error is something `TRY` can `CATCH`? If we resolve the syntax error, does that guarantee that the try block works?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is halting prematurely rather than executing the `catch` block.  The unsatisfying answer is that this is one of those things that [`TRY/CATCH` doesn't handle](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/try-catch-doesnt-handle/).

SQL Server starts the transaction, creates the table, and then crashes with

> Msg 10709, Level 16, State 1, Line 117
> The number of columns for each row in a table value constructor must be the same.

leaving the open transaction (which is why you can't fetch the other tables in Mgmt Studio).

```sql
begin try
    begin tran
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE](
        [Id] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    insert into [dbo].[MY_TABLE] (Id,Name) values ('1','Vampire'),  ('2')
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    print 'Now inside the "catch" block.  You will not see this message.';
    rollback tran
end catch

go
select * from MY_TABLE;
select @@trancount as TranCount;

rollback tran;
```

Output is as follows.  Note the existence of the table and the open transaction:

```
Msg 10709, Level 16, State 1, Line 117
The number of columns for each row in a table value constructor must be the same.
Id         Name
---------- ----------

(0 rows affected)

  TranCount
-----------
          1

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Yes. I think it's the syntax error that is causing this lock. So if the syntax was correct and the script returned another type of error inside the transaction, would my code work?

Comment: Because that is basically why we use these transactions. If it goes halfway and then halts the process in the middle of a run, then what is the point of having them. So, say, I correct the syntax error, I need to know then that the rest is ok.

Comment: Yes, if the syntax were correct chances are any other errors that are likely to crop up would indeed get caught as expected.  In your catch block, though, do pay attention to [`xact_state`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806018/12859753) and take the appropriate action based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

The script has not been executed. It is only a syntax errore that cause the script to throw an error before execution. Nothing has began to be executed.

Comment: So why does it wait for `commit` if it's not executed?

Comment: A transaction is a state of a session. In your case in explicit mode. It is not an "execution" code. Begin TRY does not capture the syntax error. But the state is still in an explicit transaction because the syntax error occur after the transaction state has been raised... In other words, the réally executed sequence is BEGIN TRAN CREATE TABLE then  syntax error.... no COMMIT, NO ROLLBACK