# Try Catch block not catching error message in SQL Server update statement

Tags: sql-server, database, try-catch

```
BEGIN TRY
   
    update   OPENQUERY(SALESFORCE_TEST, ' Select Id1, trSiteID__c, Sync_Status__c, TR_Sync_Error_Message__c FROM Site__c Where id = ''a101W000008eFx0QAE'' ')

    SET  trSiteID__c = '430075' ,
         Sync_Status__C = 'Synced' ,
         TR_Sync_Error_Message__c = '';

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
END CATCH
```

[image]

I wanted the highlighted part as the error message this is returned from the linked server.

Comment: Please post the update statement. Its hard to make wild guess just from the error message.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556941/12859753) on a similar issue with a try/catch block.  Unfortunately, there are certain classes of error that try/catch doesn't handle.

Comment: You're effectively getting a compilation error. You can't catch such errors in a `catch` block that's part of code that won't even compile, let alone start running.

Comment: hi, Paone and Bill Jetzer i have updated the question with details